# Avoid using browser.sleep with protractor and aurelia framework e2e tests

Tags: protractor, aurelia

What is the best way to avoid using browser.sleep when writing end to end (e2e) tests using protractor in aurelia js application ?

Or is there any other framework who is more suitable for e2e tests with aurelia ?

PS: i use aurelia Cli and typescript

Thanks

Comment: I think you are on the right track with Protractor http://blog.aurelia.io/2015/02/16/end-to-end-testing-with-aurelia-and-protractor/

Comment: Ok; but  how to avoid using browser.sleep() ?

Comment: Can you give a code example about what your exact problem is. It could be in the app / the testscript, so it's not clear how to answer your question.

Answer (score 0):

Using browser sleep is never a good idea the best thing to do is to wait for an element by using the then function to do so, take a look the sample code bellow.

```
element(by.xpath("xpath")).click().then(function(){
      var list = element(by.id('id'));
      var until = protractor.ExpectedConditions;
      browser.wait(until.presenceOf(list), 80000, 'Message: took too long');
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

Sometimes browser.sleep is unavoidable, but you're right in wanting to try and be smarter about it wherever possible.

Here is an example function where, if it is called, it will wait for an element with the class "toast-message" for a maximum of 30 seconds:

```
var WaitForToast = function(timeout = 30000) {
  var el = element(by.css('.toast-message'));
  var EC = protractor.ExpectedConditions;
  browser.wait(EC.presenceOf(el), timeout).then(function(){
    return;
  });
}
```

The opposite is also possible - waiting for something to go away. In this example, the code waits for a maximum of 15 seconds for an element with the class "modal-spinner" to go away:

```
var WaitForModalSpinner = function(timeout = 15000) {
  var el = element(by.css('.modal-spinner'));
  var EC = protractor.ExpectedConditions;
  browser.wait(EC.not(EC.presenceOf(el)), timeout).then(function(){
    return;
  });
};
```